# Dit-on que quelque chose est inversible « à propos de » la loi de composition ?

Tags: prépositions, mathématiques, locutions

J’ai besoin une meilleure de façon d’exprimer ceci :

> Dans un anneau *R*, tout élément est inversible à propos de sa première loi de composition « + ».

Je cherche à dire :

> Pour tout *x* dans *R*, il y a un *y* dans *R* tel que *x+y=0*. (On ne dit rien sur l’autre loi.)

Peut-être que c’est une phrase tordue en raison des mots « à propos de ». J’ai réfléchi sur cette tournure, mais je ne sais pas comment je peux l’améliorer. J’espère que vous connaissiez des mots qui conviennent mieux ici.

Comment: Je dirais « par rapport à la loi + », mais peut-être y a-t-il une construction plus heureuse qui ne me revient pas.

Comment: Ah, quand même? Jadis, je m’étais habitué à l’utilisation de ces mots, mes plus tard j’ai lu que « par rapport à » et « en comparaison avec » se ressemblaient fort. Cela m’avait convaincu qu’un tel emploi « par rapport à » était du français retors. Mais si vous dites que ça va, je me fie entièrement à vous.

Comment: C'est clairement tordu. Il n'y a dans ce cas de rapport à rien du tout puisque la loi en question sert à définir ce dont on parle. *Par rapport à* est la locution prépositionnelle poubelle que beaucoup de français utilisent quand il ne savent pas quoi utiliser, quelques un s'en moquent, personnellement je le déplore car lorsqu'elle est bien utilisée la locution est utile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

J'aurais dit « Dans un anneau *A*, tout élément est inversible pour la loi d'addition ».

Ce qui me vient le plus naturellement: « Dans un anneau *A*, tout élément possède un opposé pour la loi d'addition »

Apparemment, dans quelques cours trouvés en ligne (sur les groupes en particulier), on parle plutôt de symétrique :

> [tout élément *a* de *A* admet un symétrique pour la loi *+*](http://perso.univ-rennes1.fr/laurent.moret-bailly/docpedag/polys/polyALG98.pdf)
>
> [Tout élément *a* admet un symétrique](http://www.math.u-psud.fr/%7Eharari/exposes/groupes.pdf)

[Wikipédia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groupe_%28math%C3%A9matiques%29?oldformat=true#Remarque_sur_le_vocabulaire) propose de nommer les x<sup>-1</sup> « opposé » pour la loi d'addition et « inverse » pour la loi de multiplication. Je trouve ça plus facile a comprendre.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the answer suggesting the word *pour*. I think that's what's most common. However, an alternative might be "relativement à la loi d'addition."